# Accessing Windows Media Player's Playback Speed controls

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vb6, wmp

Is there a way to access WMP10+'s playback speed controls in a dotnet app?

[User level information on the Playback control information](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/knowledgecenter/howto/PlayFaster_how_to.aspx)

Comment: So you want to speed up the content?  Are you using the MediaElement or MediaPlayer objects?

Comment: I'm not using anything yet.  I am just looking into how to do it whatever way it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a MediaElement object, I would suggest adjusting the [SpeedRatio property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.speedratio.aspx).  Here is an [example from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748248.aspx).

From your comment, it sounds like the SpeedRatio is the way to go.  Because it allows you to adjust the playback speed.  The MediaElement or MediaPlayer is basically just a Windows Media Player.

Answer (score 10):

Add the **AxWMPLib** to your VB/C# project.
Add an **AxWindowsMediaPlayer** control to your form.

Use the following method to access playback rate:

```
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "e:\song.mp3"
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.rate = 0.5
```

*Note that rate may not always be available depending on the media type. A safer method of accessing rate would look like:

```
If (player.settings.isAvailable("Rate")) Then
    player.settings.rate = 0.5
End If
```

If that isn't what you're looking for, there also exists the MediaPlayer COM object. I didn't investigate it thoroughly, but intellisense yielded:

```
Dim mpMediaPlayer As New MediaPlayer.MediaPlayer
mpMediaPlayer.FileName = "e:\song.mp3"
mpMediaPlayer.Rate = 0.5
mpMediaPlayer.Play()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This method is not working when I'm using online URL like: mpMediaPlayer.FileName = "http://example.com/example.mp4"